# Change the price of items in the magento cart

Tags: php, magento

For a Magento web-store I have to change with percentages in a tier list.
example: so if you buy one you pay 105%, 2 103% etc.
the logic and all works but when I say to Magento: "hey make for product x price y" thee price doesn't get updated.

This is the code in the observer:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/session');                     
foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {                                           
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {                                               
        $item = $item->getParentItem();             
    }
    //loads more attributes for the rpoduct
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

    //gets the string for all percentages example:  1:105;2:103
    $staffeltext = $product['staffel_percentage'];

    $percentage = 105;// init standard percentage
    $quantity = $item->getQty();    
    $staffelarray = explode(';', $staffeltext);

    foreach($staffelarray as $staffels) {
        $stafel = explode(':', $staffels);
        if($quantity >= $stafel[0]) {
            $percentage = $stafel[1];
        }
    }
    echo $percentage . "    ";

    $currency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate();  
    $specialPrice = (($this->CalculatePrice($item) * $currency)* $percentage) / 100;                            

    echo $specialPrice;
    $specialPrice = number_format($specialPrice, 2);
    $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

This is the event that I currently use:

```
<checkout_cart_product_update_after>
```

Comment: what is show currently to you?

Comment: the problem is solved for me but i saw price each: 4,50 and subtotal 4,50 while i set the price behind the scenes to 5,00.